# Allow HTTP web application to open custom protocol without being prompted always

Tags: google-chrome, browser, protocol-handler

I have a web application that opens a local application on client machines using a protocol already registered during client setup.
The web application gives an alert when opening local application and gives a checkbox to be selected in that alert. If checkbox is checked, the browser doesn't prompt next time when opening the local application.

However, this checkbox is seen when my web application is hosted with https. When hosted with http, the checkbox is not given by the browser and the browser always throws the alert. Can the user at client side manually do something to avoid the alert every time?

I looked into the Google chrome settings. There is Protocol Handlers in Site Settings but it doesn't allow to enter a site manually. It shows outlook.office.com which I can remove but doesn't give a way to enter a site manually.

Is there a workaround to trust a site and not show alert for this specific trusted site

Answer (score 0):

If your environment is Microsoft, with a GPO the website can be added in the safe list address of Internet Explorer options. Otherwise, you will have to do it manually in each endpoint.